# How can I use wget, grep or curl to accept a list of urls(.txt) and get all the links on the websites mentioned in that list?

Tags: curl, terminal, grep, screen-scraping, wget

I have a list of urls called list.txt

I would like to use wget, curl or grep to get all the urls on the websites mentioned in that list. How can I do that?

Please do not suggest scrapy as I have tried that and it just gets complex at one point. I am using scrapy along with beautifulsoup4 and urllib2 to get all the urls from my companies search engine.

I donot mind using any other terminal tool that you could suggest. At the end I plan on exporting this list(.txt) into a mysql db so that it can be searchable.

Thanks.

Comment: `wget -i list.txt` - reads URLs from `list.txt`

Comment: @ewcz that gets me the whole site and not the urls only!

Comment: ah, so you want to extract the links contained in the urls in the input list?